# Can not read MongoDB secondary node by Spark in scala

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I wrote a Spark code to read data from MongoDB via Scala. Some of the code examples as following:

```
val mongoConfig = new Configuration()
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.uri","mongodb://secondarydb.test.local/testdb.test?readPreference=secondary")
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[5]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(mongoConfig,classOf[MongoInputFormat],classOf[Object], classOf[BSONObject])
```

I did add **readPreference=secondary**, but I still get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoNotPrimaryException:
 The server is not the primary and did not execute the operation
```

Comment: What is the IP address you are actually using? I see no replicaSet option on the connection string and this would indicate you are attempting to connect directly to a secondary node by it's address. Don't do that. Instead connect to the replicaSet with the secondary read preference. Then it's not an issue.

Comment: I'm using secondary mongoDB ip. Do you mean that I should set the ip is primary mongoldb? how can I connect to the replicates please?

Comment: The [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) is documented and consistent for all official drivers, or anything that implements them. The typical way to connect to a replica set is using the [`replicaSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.replicaSet) option with it's "name" in the URI along with a semi-colon `;` separated list of "seed" hosts. Even **one** host is actually sufficient as the driver will "auto discover" the members. But it's usually advised to provide more than one in case a member is down

Comment: So unless that option is present ( as well as your `readPreference` ) the driver interprets this as a "single host connection" only. Since the node you are connecting to "is not the primary" or aware of the primary from the driver's perspective, you get the error. You only ever connect "directly" to single hosts in a replica set for special administrative purpose. NOT for general query.